# Login User with Angular / Firestore with Authentication

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am new with Angular and firebase.

I am building a login with Firebase Database and firebase Authentication.

My problem is that every user has "personal" fields that the authentication doesn't send.
like "First name", "Last Name", "initials".

Updating the user data runs into an error like:

> FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field firstName in document users/JvFXs2i9l1VokaAJ1Cov3SBTKkn2)

What is the best approach to solve this? I am not sure if valueChange(), get() or similar things aren't a bit too much for this problem?
Can I avoid the set() method from updating the fields that weren't changed?

```
/* Setting up user data when sign in with username/password, 
  sign up with username/password and sign in with social auth  
  provider in Firestore database using AngularFirestore + AngularFirestoreDocument service */
  SetUserData(user: any, firstName?: string, lastName?: string, initials?: string, projects?: any[]) {
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(
      `users/${user.uid}`
    );


    const userData: User = {
      uid: user.uid,
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName, 
      initials: initials,
      email: user.email,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
      projects: projects 
    };


    return userRef.set(userData, {
      merge: true,
    });
  }
```

I couldn't find a proper solution between get(), valueChanges() on the internet